# Programmatically create a grouping column for data between a set of ranges

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create a grouping column in a R data.table which would allow me to group data according to a specific table of codes that would be determined by the range between items in the code vector.

I have tried playing around with run length encoding using a series of conditions but this seems very cumbersome and doesn't return the exact results I require

```
library(data.table)

t <- seq.int(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 10)
data <- rnorm(10)

dt <- data.table(t, data)

code_t <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7)
codes <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

code_dt <- data.table(code_t, codes)
```

I would like it to return a new column in dt that would group the data with the appropriate code as such:

```
            t       data code
 1: 0.0000000 -0.8502317 <NA>
 2: 0.1111111  0.4148730 <NA>
 3: 0.2222222  0.4107869    A
 4: 0.3333333  3.2112218    B
 5: 0.4444444  0.2000562    B
 6: 0.5555556 -0.4340153    B
 7: 0.6666667  0.6888978    C
 8: 0.7777778  1.5207119    D
 9: 0.8888889  0.1829433    D
10: 1.0000000 -0.4255971    D
```

Comment: What would happen when multiple `code` fall within the interval between `t` and `data`. Row 9 matches A, B, C and D...

Comment: @Wimpel I think you have misunderstood the question. The `data` column is for illustrative purposes only in the example (my bad). The intervals for the code assignment is determined by adjacent members of `code_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert of `data.table` package but I would solve your problem as follows. First I load the package

```r
# packages
library(data.table)
```

then I create the same vectors as you did

```r
# data
t <- seq.int(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 10)
data <- rnorm(10)
code_t <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7)
codes <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

and then I cut the `t` vector using the `cut` function according to the breaks given in the `code_t` vector and assign the labels defined in `codes`. Note that if I simply set `breaks = code_t` then the breaks are `(0.2, 0.3]`, `(0.3, 0.6]`, `(0.6, 0.7]`. I need to set `breaks = c(code_t, 1)` to include also `(0.7, 1]` but you should change it according to your use case.

```r
code <- cut(t, breaks = c(code_t, 1), labels = codes)
```

This is the result.

```r
data.table(t, data, code)
#>             t        data code
#>  1: 0.0000000  0.99654798 <NA>
#>  2: 0.1111111 -0.18082732 <NA>
#>  3: 0.2222222 -0.28364311    A
#>  4: 0.3333333 -0.11504042    B
#>  5: 0.4444444 -1.37218034    B
#>  6: 0.5555556  0.02826155    B
#>  7: 0.6666667  1.57980554    C
#>  8: 0.7777778 -0.59016497    D
#>  9: 0.8888889  1.00988949    D
#> 10: 1.0000000  0.42934448    D
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Excellent, cut always seems to be the answer to my needs but I never see the implementation immediately. Thank you!

I used your direction to implement this in data.table

dt[, code := cut(t, breaks = c(coded_1, 1), labels = codes)]

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, `data.table` allows for *rolling joins* which is an alternative to [`cut()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890655/3817004) or to [*non-equi joins*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57891383/3817004):

```
library(data.table)
dt[, codes := code_dt[dt, on = .(code_t = t), roll = TRUE, x.codes]]
dt
```

> ```
>             t       data codes
>  1: 0.0000000  0.4728356  <NA>
>  2: 0.1111111 -0.1761036  <NA>
>  3: 0.2222222 -0.5259357     A
>  4: 0.3333333  0.9995843     B
>  5: 0.4444444 -0.3971852     B
>  6: 0.5555556  1.3734871     B
>  7: 0.6666667 -1.5221889     C
>  8: 0.7777778  0.3299245     D
>  9: 0.8888889 -0.9149123     D
> 10: 1.0000000 -1.1195691     D
> ```

Comment: This is the real, extendable answer. Even though it's possible with `cut`, a rolling join is going to be waaaaay faster if the data is big.

Comment: @Uwe interesting. Our answers are very similar. Perhaps you have something to say about the differences?

Comment: I would have thought so to @PavoDive but when I benchmark the cut method from agila vs the rolling joins method from Uwe on my real data the cut method comes out much faster. The other advantage of the cut method is it also allows me easily to input custom breaks if I do not want to apply the labelling across the entire dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dt[, code := code_dt[.SD, on = .(code_t <= t), mult = "last", codes]]
dt
#             t       data code
#  1: 0.0000000  1.4093115 <NA>
#  2: 0.1111111 -0.5233412 <NA>
#  3: 0.2222222  0.6517409    A
#  4: 0.3333333  0.5204115    B
#  5: 0.4444444 -1.1126457    B
#  6: 0.5555556  0.5156077    B
#  7: 0.6666667 -0.6376642    C
#  8: 0.7777778  0.2816557    D
#  9: 0.8888889  0.1195879    D
# 10: 1.0000000 -1.8018463    D
```

Answer (score -1):

I have written a function that can be easily extended and manipulated. I tested the code and it worked without needing to load any libraries.

```
assingGroups <- function(x,ranges,codes){
cnt=1;
  for (i in ranges[-length(ranges)]){
    mask <- x$t >= ranges[cnt] & x$t<ranges[cnt+1]
    x$grouped[mask] <- codes[cnt] 
    cnt<-cnt+1;
  }

  ### assign the last name to remaining 'NA'
  x$grouped[x$grouped=='NA'] <-codes[cnt]
  return(x)
}
```

This function receives a dataframe with at least two columns named as "t" and "grouped". The ranges is a vector containing any arbitrary values. you should notice that a vector with four numbers denotes three intervals!
after running the above function use the following codes to see the results:

```
code_t <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7)
codes <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
dt=data.frame(c(runif(10,0,1)),rep('NA',10),stringsAsFactors =FALSE) 
colnames(dt) <- c("t","grouped")
dt
```

now dataframe looks like:

```
>dt
        t       grouped
1  0.20846488      NA
2  0.62090310      NA
3  0.43246382      NA
4  0.24366974      NA
5  0.34148940      NA
6  0.01985644      NA
7  0.52140747      NA
8  0.09040793      NA
9  0.47128141      NA
10 0.62571187      NA
```

Now simply run the function to get your new data frame:

```
dt<- assingGroups(dt,code_t,codes)
force(dt)
```

you will see the results as:

```
> force(dt)
        t       grouped
1  0.20846488       A
2  0.62090310       C
3  0.43246382       B
4  0.24366974       A
5  0.34148940       B
6  0.01985644       D
7  0.52140747       B
8  0.09040793       D
9  0.47128141       B
10 0.62571187       C
```

Comment: Please, consider to review your answer. The OP was asking about to group `t` - not `data`. Your answer might be correct but is applied to the wrong column of `dt`. Thank you.

Comment: what I wrote is a general-purpose function that can be applied on any columns a in data frame. The columns in the data frame can be renamed to suit different problems. for instance, `colnames(dt) <- c("t","grouped")`, however, in the function the  field should be updated. anyway, I just renamed the data to t!